# IndexError: too many indices for np.array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I wish to do something like this where I have an ndarray containing coordinates, and one containing values, as required by scipy.interpolate.griddata

```
import numpy
p = {(1,2):10, (0,2):12, (2,0):11}
coords, values = np.array([(np.array(k),v) for k,v in p.items()]).T
```

However, I also want to be able to do the following:

```
x = coords[:,0]
y = coords[0,:]
np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():5j, y.min():y.max():5j]
```

but, I am getting the error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

for `x = coords[:,0].`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put `np.array` into `np.array`, the inner `np.array` is a whole and not recognizable to the outer `np.array`. In fact, your `coords` has shape `(3,)`.

Correct way:

```
coordsx, coordsy, values = np.array([(kx, ky, v) for (kx, ky), v in p.items()]).T
```

Comment: How do I produce coords from coordsx, coordsy?

Comment: `np.stack((coordsx, coordsy)).T`, then `[:,0]` is x, `[:,1]` is y.